# Gradient-based optimization of $n$ functions

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I appreciate the willingness of everyone to assist me in advance.

I am faced with a set of $n$ distinct convex optimization problems, each defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
\max\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m} f(x) + g_i(x),
\end{equation}

where $f$ and $(g_i)_{i \in [[1,n]]}$ are concave functions, and

\begin{equation}
g_i(x) \leq g_{i+1}(x) \hspace{0.4cm} \forall i \in [[1,n-1]], \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^m.
\end{equation}

While the computation of $f(x_0)$, $\nabla f(x_0)$, and $\nabla g_i(x_0)$ for a given $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is computationally expensive, evaluating $g_i(x_0)$ is fast for all $i \in [[1,n]]$.

A first approach would be to solve each optimization problem independently. However, other methods would benefit from the fact that the function $f$ is common to all the optimization problems. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess form a philosophical standpoint this is hopeless. For example, if your $g_i$'s force the $n$ maximum points $x_i$ of each optimization problems to be far apart from each other, then in fact for the i-th probelm you could modify $f$ in an arbitrary fashion far away from $x_i$ without essentially modifying the i-th problem. Thus each problem eventually "sees a different $f_i$" (i-e the restriction of $f$ to disjoint neighborhoods of each $x_i$). With this in mind, I really don't see how you could leverage the fact that $f$ is common?